Discriminative vs generative & Bayes risk
In the context of binary classification with features denoted $X$ and labels $y$, one could specify the joint distribution of $(X, y)$ in two equivalent but different ways :

The generative way specifying this joint distribution through the prior and class-conditional densities,
The discriminative through the posterior probability $\eta(X) = \mathbb{P}(y = 0|X)$ and the distribution of $X$.

That concerns only the underlying Bayesian model.
Now, consider $l$ a loss function. From the generative point of view, the Bayes risk can be definied as :
$$\underset{T : \mathcal{X} \to \Theta}{\inf} \mathbb{E}_{X, \theta}[l(T(X), \theta)],$$
where the infimum applies to estimators of the label.
In Reid and Williamson, the authors adopt a more discriminative point of view in page 16/17 (indexed 746/747 in the document) by defining the loss of an estimate $\hat{\eta}$ of the posterior probability. Then we consider the Bayes risk where the infimum applies to estimators of the posterior probability.
Then it is claimed that these two Bayes risks coincide (which is quite intuitive since the two specifications of the joint distribution are equivalent).
Can someone help me prove formally that it is the case ?
